# Can't find Datasnap option on my Delphi 10.4 ide

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

How can I add Datasnap option under Delphi to access the three different wizards in the datasnap catogory (DataSnap REST Application, Datasnap Server, dataSanp WebBroker)?

[image]

Comment: Did you install DataSnap at all? Also what's your used Edition, in case that matters?

Comment: How do I install datasnap. Was not able to find it on GetIt

Comment: DataSnap is available only in Enterprise & Architect editions not in Professional.

Comment: During the Delphi setup. But you still didn't answer which edition you use.

Comment: I thinnk mine is a professional edition.

Comment: If you have the Professional Edition, you don't have DataSnap. It's only available in the higher editions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataSnap is available only in Enterprise & Architect editions not in Professional.